# how to setup url referer in AWS EC2, Apache and Laravel environment

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, payment-gateway

We are trying to integrate a payment gateway solution into our app. We are using AWS EC2, Apache and Laravel for the server environment. The instruction has a point that I am not able to understand.

> Enable your URL Referrer, this can mostly be done by contacting your
> Hosting service. Your URL Referrer should be the same as your Return
> URL

Can someone explain whether this needs to be done on AWS end, Laravel end, apache or where do I need to set this up?

Regards
Syed

Comment: Is that all the detail it gives? Any kind of example of what it should look like? Because honestly, that makes no sense to me as someone who has been working in web development for nearly 20 years, during which time I've integrated nearly a dozen different payment systems. Maybe contact their support team and ask for clearer instructions.

Comment: about the url referer, they only gave this info. Merchants website should follow the https protocol in order to complete integration with APG
 Enable your URL Referrer, this can mostly be done by contacting your Hosting service. Your URL Referrer should be the same as your Return URL (set in merchant portal in step 3 above) You can get more information on this by visiting the link below. https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1561789561-A-mini-guide-to-HTTP-referer.

Comment: The rest of the guide is about various parameters of the gateway but they have said little about the URL referer.

Comment: It means request initiator and webhook url must be same I don't  think you need to do anything if the domain urls are same

Answer (score 0):

It means request initiator (from where you are calling payment gateway service) and webhook url (the url you will configure to get response back from payment gateay service) must be same I don't think you need to do anything if both the domain urls are same.